# Dynamically bind checkboxes on textbox change event MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In my Model

```
namespace Mvcautocomplete.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        public string productName { get; set; }
        public int productId { get; set; }
        public List<Product> GetProducts()
        {
            List<Product> lst = new List<Product>();
            lst.Add(new Product { productName = "Andhra Pradesh",productId=1 });
            lst.Add(new Product { productName = "Assam" ,productId=2});
            lst.Add(new Product { productName = "Hyderabad",productId=3 });
            lst.Add(new Product { productName = "India",productId=4 });
            lst.Add(new Product { productName = "Bangalore",productId=5 });

        return lst;

    }

    public List<Dose> DoseCollection
    {
        get
        {
            List<Dose> lst = new List<Dose>();
            lst.Add(new Dose {doseId = 1, doseName = "A.05", prodId = new Product { productId = 1 } });
            lst.Add(new Dose {doseId=2, doseName = "B.05",prodId=new Product{productId=1} });
            return lst;
        }
    }

}

public class Dose
{
    public int doseId { get; set; }
    public string doseName { get; set; }
    public Product prodId { get; set; }
    public bool isSelected { get; set; }
}
```

}

In controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {          

        Product obj = new Product();
        return View(obj);
    }
```

In view I have textbox for ProductName which is autocomplete.now I want to populate Dosename based on productName on textbox on change event.

Now how to create and bind checkboxes based on product name entered?

Comment: Could you show your view code and explain more precisely what you are trying to achieve there?